# Surjectivity of maps between spheres

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, differential-topology

I am wondering how to prove that a non-zero degree map from $S^n \to S^n$ is surjective. For example, identifying $S^1 \subset \mathbb{C}$, we can take $f:S^1 \to S^1$ via $f(z) = z^k$ with $k\neq 0$. This is a map of degree $k$. How can I show that it is surjective?

Comment: Hello, it is not a homework problem. I am learning myself the subject and have found those exercises. But I am not sure what you mean with the factor over a map to the sphere without a point.

Comment: Hint: Use proof by contradiction, homotopy invariance of the degree and the fact that if f is not surjective, we can decompose it into an inclusion and a map to the sphere without a point.

Comment: I'd answer but the question is closed. This is actually easy to see. Take any point not in the image and remove it; now you have a map into a contractible space, so it is nulhomotopic, hence has degree 0.

Comment: Oh, this is MO. I thought I was on MSE. Yes this question is inappropriate for this site, try MSE.